# How to search each line of a file in another file using python?

Tags: python, file, with-statement

My expected_cmd.txt (say f1) is

```
mpls ldp
snmp go
exit
```

and my configured.txt (say f2) is

```
exit
```

Here is the code I'm trying with, **searching all lines of f1 in f2**

```
with open('expected_cmd.txt', 'r') as rcmd, open('%s.txt' %configured, 'r') as f2:
    for line in rcmd:
            print 'line present is ' + line
            if line in f2:
                    continue
            else:
                    print line
```

So basically I'm trying to print the line from first file that is not present in the second file.
But with above code I'm getting output as

```
#python validateion.py
line present is mpls ldp

mpls ldp

line present is snmp go 

snmp go 

line present is exit

exit
```

Not sure why is it printing `exit` which is matched.

Also I'm wondering if there a built-in function to do this in python ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open('%s.txt' %configured,'r') as f2:
    cmds = set(i.strip() for i in f2)
with open('expected_cmd.txt', 'r') as rcmd:
    for line in rcmd:
            if line.strip() in cmds:
                    continue
            else:
                    print line
```

This fixed my issue.

Comment: Exactly. You now read `f2` only once, so you avoid the original problem.

Answer (score 0):

The file object, which you get when you `open` a file contains information about the file and the current location within file. The position is the beginning of the file by default when you open it in `'r'` mode1.

When you read some data from the file (or write to it), the position moves. For instance, `f.read()` reads everything and moves to the end of the file. A repeated `f.read()` reads nothing.

A similar thing happens when you iterate through file (e.g. `line in f2`).

I would suggest that, unless the files are many gigabytes in size, you should read both files and then do the rest of the logic in memory, e.g.:

```
with open('expected_cmd.txt', 'r') as f1:
    lines1 = list(f1)

with open('%s.txt' %configured, 'r') as f2:
    lines2 = list(f2)
```

Then you can implement the logic:

```
for line in lines1:
    if line not in lines2:
        print(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

You read the configured.txt fully and do the search by stripping the lines in rcmd.